# Raspberry Pi check WLan Connection with PHP

Tags: php, linux, raspberry-pi, debian, wifi

I'm currently working with a Pi for the first time and would like to build a system for my Pi that works like this:

I'm using the headless OS with 64 bits.

When you start the Pi, it checks whether it has a WiFi connection, if so it opens a browser in full-screen mode and connects to a specific website and displays it, for example, on a television etc. If it doesn't have a connection, I installed an access point using the following tutorial https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/89803/access-point-as-wifi-router-repeater-optional-with-bridge/89804#89804. I then installed an Apache2 + PHP web server and built a website on the Pi that scans all available WiFi when called using the following PHP script.

```
<?php

$result = shell_exec('sudo iwlist wlan0 scan');
$networks = explode('Cell', $result);

unset($networks[0]);
$data = [];
$cachedNetworks = [];

foreach ($networks as $item) {

    $pattern = '/Address:(.*?)Channel:(.*?)Frequency:(.*?)GHz.*?Quality=(.*?)\/(.*?) Signal level=(.*?) dBm.*?ESSID:"(.*?)"/s';
    preg_match($pattern, $item, $matches);

    if ((!in_array($matches[7], $cachedNetworks)) && ($matches[7] != '')) {
        $cachedNetworks[] = $matches[7];
        $data[] = array(
            'Address' => trim($matches[1]),
            'Channel' => trim($matches[2]),
            'Frequency' => trim($matches[3]),
            'Quality' => trim($matches[4]),
            'MaxQuality' => trim($matches[5]),
            'SignalLevel' => trim($matches[6]),
            'ESSID' => trim($matches[7])
        );
    }
}


echo json_encode($data, true);
```

I process the data via Javascript when the page is accessed and every 10 seconds to update it.

Well... As soon as all the WLANs are listed, I built a function to give the associated WLAN a password and, after clicking on "Connect", to transmit the ESSID and the password to the following script:

```
<?php

$psk = $_GET["password"];
$response['success'] = false;

$fileContent = "country=DE
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid=\"" . $_GET['ssid'] . "\"
    psk=\"" . $_GET['password'] . "\"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}";

// Check paths and make sure the file is writable
$filePath = '/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf';

if (is_writable($filePath)) {
    // Datei überschreiben
    file_put_contents($filePath, $fileContent);

    $response['response'] = "The file was successfully overwritten.";
} else {
    $response['response'] = "The file cannot be overwritten. Please check the file permissions.";
    return;
}


//Check Connection

$t = exec("sudo wpa_cli -i wlan0 reconfigure");

$output = shell_exec("/sbin/iwconfig wlan0");

if (strpos($output, 'Frequency:') !== false) {
    $response['success'] = true;
    $response['response'] = "connected. T:".$t." Res:".$output;
} else {
    $fileContent = "country=DE
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1";
    file_put_contents($filePath, $fileContent);
    $response['response'] = "Not connected. T:".$t." Res:".$output;
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

I replace the WLAN configuration file with the corresponding data and then want to check the connection with `exec("sudo wpa_cli -i wlan0 reconfigure")`. When I enter the commands in the Pi's terminal everything works fine. However, if I run the command via PHP I get the following error: 'RECONFIGURE' command timed out.

At best, the access point connection between the Pi and the device should remain in place as soon as the Pi checks the WiFi connection. Therefore I have ruled out restarting Wifi

I would be happy if someone has an idea to fix my code or a general suggestion to do the connection check differently

Comment: Can be a permission issue, when you run the command in the terminal, it's executed with your user's permissions. In contrast, when run through PHP, it's executed with the web server's permissions, which might not have the necessary privileges to reconfigure the WiFi settings.

Comment: Hi, i gave www-data already all needed permissions...
My visudo:
`www-data ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/iwlist wlan0 scan
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /etc/wpa_supplicant
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl restart wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/iwconfig
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/wpa_cli -i wlan0 reconfigure`

Comment: Do a `sudo -u www-data ...` call in the terminal to verify that it's indeed a non-permissions issue.

Comment: I gave the permissions with your command but still not working